# ¿Cómo hacer para llamar varias funciones a través de otra función "general"?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

He creado 4 funciones, 3 de las cuales deben insertar valores (comisiones para cada uno de los empleados de una empresa) en determinadas columnas cada una.

Por separado funcionan bien, pero al incluirla las 4 en una sola, dejan de funcionar correctamente, empiezan a incluir valores en otras columnas que no les corresponden.

Existe otra forma de llamar funciones dentro de otra función?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenida/o a [es.so]: haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y lee [ask]. ¡NO ES NECESARIO QUE GRITES! Además, el código siempre _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta.

Comment: Por favor include un [mcve] y describe brevemente que es lo que debe hacer. También sería bueno que indicaras porque estas usando un while en lugar de un if.

Comment: por qué escribir una función para cada empleado en vez de crear una función para todos los empleados, y una clase para  poner los datos que cada empleado puede tener, y luego poner en una matriz cada objeto de esa clase.

Answer (score 0):

No nos muestras el código que hace cada función, pero suponiendo que cada funcion ingresa los datos de acuerdo a lo que hizo la función anterior, podríamos inferir que debes actualizar/refrescar la información de la hoja antes de llamar a la otra función.

Esto lo puedes hacer a través de `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` pones esta línea de código antes que finalice cada función por ejemplo.

```
function Agregar_Producto_Factura(){
  // Codigo ya implementado va aquí
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

Espero te sirva.